# Share stack between different Bash Terminals

Tags: bash, terminal, stack

Is there any way to share the stack between two different bash terminal windows?

So if I were to do `pushd` (or an equivalent of) in one terminal window and then `popd` in another window it would access the same stack.

This would be massively useful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by writing a couple bash scripts.

gpushd (global pushd)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

filename="$HOME/.gstack.dirs"
newdir=$(readlink -f "$1")

if [ "$newdir" != "" ]; then
    echo $newdir >> $filename
else
    newdir=$(readlink -f ".")
    echo $newdir >> $filename
fi
```

gpopd (this needs to be put in .bashrc)

```sh
function gpopd() {
 filename="$HOME/.gstack.dirs"
 dir=$(tail -n 1 $filename)
 sed -i '$ d' $filename

 if [ "$dir" != "" ]; then
  cd "$dir"
 fi
}
```

I wanted to put both in `/usr/bin` but gpopd could not change directories so had to be moved to a function in .bashrc. Hope this helps anyone who had a similar issue!